# WCF Restful Service - Implement Asynchronous Operations

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, asynchronous, task

Alright, I am needing some clarification and validation with whether or not implementing async on the server is recommended and how.

First, here are some details of my service:

- Hosted in IIS 8.5 on a server with Server 2012 R2.
- Uses .NET 4.5 and can use 4.6 or greater. There is no restriction here.
- WCF Restful service. Concurrency Mode = Per Call.
- Client is a mobile application already awaiting every service operation call to my service.
- Literally every method calls a database, another web service (not an async web service), or generates a PDF. I am not kidding. Every. Single. Call.
- Would like to use Task-based asynchronous operations.

Now, with the above in mind I read that making the service operations asynchronous will help with the I/O operations (i.e long running database, external web service calls, pdf generation, etc). However, I cannot seem to find a good consensus on how to do just that.

Stephen Clearly seems like a pretty knowledgeable guy, however one of his blogs said to never use Task.Run on a web service which I would assume I would have to use on the method making the database/web service calls on my own WCF service in order to make it asynchronous. (source: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html). He recommends using Task.FromResult? My results cannot/should not be cached though?

So, when my service gets a request it obviously creates a thread for that request. And since literally every request will be making one or more database calls there will be an I/O operation. I would like that thread to go service another persons incoming request rather than be tied up on that I/O operation, hence the point to go with asynchronous service operations, and once that database call is finished (I/O operation) a thread picks up where that original request left off. How exactly do I accomplish this in code?

Here is a sample of the current (obviously) synchronous version of the code. What do I need to do to make it asynchronous as described above?

I guessing I would just async this service operation and await the call to the MobileData.GetNoteAttachmentData. What would I have to do in GetNoteAttachmentData?

Example Service Operation:

```
public NoteAttachmentContract GetNoteAttachmentData(string annotationId)
    {
        DataSet NoteAttachmentData = null;
        MobileData MobileData = new MobileData();
        NoteAttachmentContract Result = null;
        TokenContract CurrentToken = MobileData.GetToken();

        try
        {
            NoteAttachmentData = MobileData.GetNoteAttachmentData(CurrentToken, annotationId);

            if (NoteAttachmentData != null && NoteAttachmentData.HasData())
            {
                DataRow NoteAttachmentRecord = NoteAttachmentData.Tables[0].Rows[0];

                string DocumentBody = NoteAttachmentRecord["documentbody"].ToString();
                string NoteId = NoteAttachmentRecord["annotationid"].ToString();
                string FileName = NoteAttachmentRecord["filename"].ToString();

                Result = new NoteAttachmentContract(DocumentBody, FileName, NoteId.IsGuid(false) ? new Guid(NoteId) : (Guid?)null);
            }
        }
        catch (MobileServiceException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new MobileServiceException(ex.Message, CurrentToken);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (NoteAttachmentData != null)
            {
                NoteAttachmentData.Dispose();
                NoteAttachmentData = null;
            }
        }

        return Result;
    }



public DataSet GetNoteAttachmentData(TokenContract token, string annotationId)
{
    DataSet Result = null;
    SqlCommand Command = null;

    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(token.ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlParameter AnnotationIdParameter = new SqlParameter();
            AnnotationIdParameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier;
            AnnotationIdParameter.ParameterName = "@AnnotationId";
            AnnotationIdParameter.Value = new Guid(annotationId);

            connection.Open();
            Command = new SqlCommand(Properties.Resources.GetNoteAttachmentData, connection);
            Command.Parameters.Add(AnnotationIdParameter);

            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Command))
            {
                adapter.Fill(Result);
                Command.Parameters.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (Result != null)
        {
            Result.Dispose();
            Result = null;
        }

        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (Command != null)
        {
            Command.Parameters.Clear();
            Command.Dispose();
        }
    }

    return Result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of using async operations in a service is to free up the thread when all you're doing is waiting for something. If your service code is only doing synchronous work, then Task.Run() allows you to free up the current thread but ends up just transferring holding on to a thread doing nothing to a different thread. Then you are just adding overhead with the extra work needed to handle managing an asynchronous operation. Unless any of the methods your operation calls have an async equivalent, you are best leaving things as they are. For example, is there a MobileData.GetNoteAttachmentDataAsync method that returns a Task? If there is, make your method async and await the response from that method.

Comment: The GetNoteAttachmentData is ran on the same exact server. I put that code in the same code tag. So I have complete control over all of the code the server touches because it is all ran from the service itself. The database call? Ran from the business object on the service, hence the "MobileData" object.

So with that being said, how can I make GetNoteAttachmentData (which is ran on the same service, on the same thread currently) be async? Should I? Cause according to what you just said all it does is pull another thread to hold onto it while it does the I/O work, which is counter productive.

Comment: And if that is true, why make asynchronous methods at all? Why not keep all web service methods synchronous even if they perform I/O work? Are tasks only useful for UI applications and only have uses for background work on web services?

Comment: At the low level win32 api, there are async variations of all the I/O operations. So anything calling an I/O api's should be calling the async versions. Most (if not all) framework api's which wrap native I/O calls expose the async variations. For example, the [FileStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class has a ReadAsync method. Somewhere, there is some code which calls an I/O method, that should be switched to use the Async version, then bubble up the async-ness so you can await on it.